# Database migration from Sybase ASE to Azure SQL managed instance

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sap-ase, azure-sql-managed-instance

We planned to migrate Sybase ASE database to Azure SQL managed instance. Our source Sybase database collation is Binary as like below

```
Character Set = 1, iso_1
ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) - Western European 8-bit character set.
Sort Order = 50, bin_iso_1
Binary ordering, for the ISO 8859/1 or Latin-1 character set ( iso_1).
```

But there are 9 types of collation in SQL as below

```
Latin1_General_BIN
Latin1_General_BIN2
Latin1_General_100_BIN
Latin1_General_100_BIN2
Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8
SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN
SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2
SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2
```

Any one please assist , which SQL collation suitable for above source Sybase collation.

Comment: Have you tried executing `sp_helpsort` against some user databases whose default collations are one of those you've listed? You're likely wanting a collation that uses Windows-1252, since that's a superset of the characters from ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Comment: Also consider not only the data you want to migrate right now but whether longer-term you want to support Unicode data as this could also impact which collation you choose.

Comment: `Latin1_General_BIN2`  looks like proper for your migration.

Comment: Thank you all for the support.Latin1_General_BIN2 works fine.